# HttpClient stuck on Android with Genymotion emulator

Tags: java, android, tomcat, servlets, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to run an HTTP request with `HttpClient` on Android.
Here is my code on Android side:

```java
httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 15000);

// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
getRequest = new HttpGet(Dictionary.MINYAN_SERVER + servlet);
getRequest.addHeader(ACCEPT, APP_JSON);

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest); //STUCKED HERE
```

If I remove the timeout setting I never get a response. With the timeout I am getting a timeout exception.

On the server side I have a simple servlet running on my localhost. Here is the code:

```java
public class Test extends HttpServlet 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        System.out.println("adasdasd asdsadsad");
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        try
        {
            obj.put("name", "vlad");
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         response.setContentType("application/json");
         response.getWriter().write(obj.toString());
    }
}
```

**Note:**

When trying to access `loclhost:8080/Test` from the browser I am getting: `{"name":"vlad"}` which is fine.

`Dictionary.MINYAN_SERVER` holds `http://10.0.2.2:8080/` and `servet` holds `Test`.

I have the Internet permission in my Manifest.xml file.

Any ideas what can I do to solve it?

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you use `URLConnection`?

Comment: It's just Java's default http client. Search here or on google and try it. You'll most likely get the same result but I'm curious.

Comment: Can it be related to the fact that my emulator runs on Genymotion?

Comment: Tried it with the `URLConnection` and still the same.

Comment: There's quite a difference between localhost and 10.0.2.2 - e.g. Firewalls, routing (even just locally). Check if you can reach the endpoint on 10.0.2.2 from your emulator with any other means, e.g. a browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so with the gr8 help of @Olaf Kock I found the solution [here](http://bbowden.tumblr.com/post/58650831283/accessing-a-localhost-server-from-the-genymotion). 
Genymotion is running on Virtualbox, and the default network configuration is “Host-Only.” This method essentially emulates a physical network that is shared by your Genymotion VM (the emulator) and your host machine. The name of the network is vboxnet0, and if you run “ifconfig vboxnet0” (or “ipconfig vboxnet0” if running Windows) on your host machine, you should receive the IP address of your host on the vboxnet0 network. The default IP is most likely `192.168.56.1`. This is the IP address to use when accessing your host machine from the Genymotion emulator.

**The url that worked for me is:**

`http://192.168.56.1:8080/`

**Update:**

You cab find your IP address ([follow this link to get your IP address](http://compnetworking.about.com/cs/windowsnetworkin1/ht/findaddrwinxp.htm)). Put this address like this: `http://ip_address:8080`. `8080` is the port of your localhost web server (tomcat default port).